# WP7 SMS delivery report application

Tags: windows-phone-7, sms

In Windows Phone 7 sms delivery reports are present in kernel, however they are not customizable. You get an sms delivery report as another sms message. But everyone knows that sms delivery report is not an sms - it's an attribute of a sent message.

iPhone has an app called iPhoneDelivery which allows to customize the way the delivery reports are presented to a user. It allows the best approach - as an icon of an envelope to an already sent sms message. Same applies to Android.

Is it possible to create such an application for Windows Phone 7 at this time? Does the WP7 SDK allow "messing" with internal sms application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current API provides no way to access previously sent SMS messages; so attributes such as delivery reports cannot be queried. The only access to SMS right now is the [SmsComposeTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.smscomposetask_members%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) but even this requires the user to hit the send button, so an app cannot automatically send text messages.

Comment: I don't need to send an sms message from my application. I need the delivery reports to be shown as envelopes on sent messages in built-in messaging application. I suppose if you can't programmatically access previously sent message, you can't do what I am inquiring about. Thank you.